# Addition and Multiplication table for Ring/Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm not sure if it's possible to show it here, but how would the

addition and multiplication table look like for R/I (where R is rings with ideal I) when 
$$
R = Z_{12} \text{ and } I = \{0,3,6,9\}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can see that there will be $3$ elements in $R / I$, they are:
$$
\widetilde{0} = 0 + I\\
\widetilde{1} = 1 + I \\
\widetilde{2} = 2 + I
$$
for any other element you can form can be broken down first $\mod{12}$ and then using the ideal $I$. Now we can construct our addition and multiplication tables:
$$
\begin{array}{l | c c c }
 * & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{1} & \widetilde{2} \\
 \hline
\widetilde{0} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{0} \\
\widetilde{1} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{1} & \widetilde{2} \\
\widetilde{2} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{2} & \widetilde{1}
\end{array}
\quad
\begin{array}{l | c c c }
 + & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{1} & \widetilde{2} \\
 \hline
\widetilde{0} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{1} & \widetilde{2} \\
\widetilde{1} & \widetilde{1} & \widetilde{2} & \widetilde{0} \\
\widetilde{2} & \widetilde{2} & \widetilde{0} & \widetilde{1}
\end{array}
$$

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: I understand when you said there's 3 elements in R/I, but how did you get the elements after?  Where you had 0=0+1...

Comment: Well by definition of the quotient ring we have elements of the form $a + I \in R/I$ where $a \in R$. I noticed that $0,1,2$ are each representatives of the three elements in this quotient ring so I name them to be the three distinct elements.

Comment: @paula000 I suppose my answer might not be explanatory enough. Can you try to explain where your confusion arises when you see how I name the three elements in $R/I$? Are you confused on the definition of $R/I$, the definition of an element in $R/I$ or something else altogether?

Comment: Ah okay.  I've briefly forgotten the definition of the quotient ring.  But yes, I believe understand everything else you explained after.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help, if you get confused later on comment again and I'll try to help out!

Comment: @DanZimm Hello, may I ask where you got those three elements?