# Make an addition and multiplication table for ring $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ with ideal $\left \{ 0,3,6,9 \right \}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, cayley-table

> Make an addition and multiplication table for ring $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$ with ideal $\left \{ 0,3,6,9 \right \}$.

I know how to make addition/multiplication tables, but I am confused as to how to find the elements for the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_{12}/\left \{ 0,3,6,9 \right \}$. [DanZimm's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/796714) mentioned the three elements but not how they arrived at them.

Comment: How familiar are you with quotient rings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I = \{0,3,6,9\}$. The elements of the quotient $\Bbb{Z}_{12}/I$ are of the form $a + I$ where $a \in \Bbb{Z}_{12}$. There are only $3$ choices:

$$
0 + I = \{0,3,6,9\} \\  1 + I = \{1,4,7,10\} \\ 2 + I = \{2, 5, 8, 11\}
$$

There are no more distinct elements. Note that $3 + I = I$ and $4 + I = 1+ I$, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for making such a clear, easy-to-understand reply!